# can I use flutter without downloading android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I was just wondering if I can use flutter without downloading Android studio because Android Studio is very heavy

Comment: I think more details on what is to be gained by not using Android Studio is needed. Otherwise it is possible that there will be many "correct" answers but none of them will answer the intended question :-)

Comment: I've wrote a [Getting Started With Flutter](https://codey.netlify.app/flutter/start) without the need for Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

You can do so, by following the below steps.

**Note**: The sum of all the downloaded files is about `1.5GB` including `VS Code`.

1. Download and install [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) `88MB`.
2. Install the `Flutter` extension, which automatically installs the `Dart` extension.
3. Download the [Flutter SDK](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases) `818MB`. Extract to `C:\Flutter`.
4. Download the [Android Command Line Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio) `115MB`. Extract to `C:\Android\cmdline-tools\latest`.
5. Download the [Android Platform Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools) `5MB`. Extract to `C:\Android\platform-tools`.
6. Download the [Java SDK](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/) (**version 17 or lower**) `171MB`. Extract to `C:\Java`.
7. In `Environment Variables` edit the `Path` system variable and add the following:
   `%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Android\platform-tools` +
   `%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Android\cmdline-tools\latest\bin` +
   `%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Flutter\bin` +
   `%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Java\bin`.
8. In `Environment Variables` add the following new system variables.
9. Name: `JAVA_HOME`. Value: `C:\Java`.
10. Name: `ANDROID_HOME`. Value: `C:\Android\cmdline-tools\latest`.
11. Name: `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`. Value: `C:\Android\cmdline-tools\latest`.
12. Run the following command as administrator: `sdkmanager --licenses`, and accept all the licenses.
13. In phone's settings, enable `Developer options` and `USB debugging`, also enable the `Developer mode` on your PC.
14. Connect your phone and make sure that all `drivers` are installed.
15. Create a new flutter project and run it using the command `flutter run`. This will download the needed files (automatically) to run the app on your phone and create an `APK` file. Download size is about `300MB`.

**Firebase [Optional]**

1. Download and install portable [Git](https://git-scm.com/downloads) `56MB`.
2. In `Environment Variables` edit the `Path` system variable and add the following:
   `%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Git\bin` +
   `%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin`
3. Download [Firebase CLI binary for Windows](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli).
4. Extract the file `firebase-tools-instant-win.exe` to the flutter project's `root` directory.
5. Copy the file `firebase-tools-instant-win.exe` and rename it `firebase.exe` in the same `root` folder.
6. Run: `dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli`.
7. Run: `flutter pub add firebase_core`.
8. Run: `flutter pub add firebase_auth`.
9. Run: `.\firebase-tools-instant-win.exe`.
10. Run: `firebase login`.
11. Run: `flutterfire configure`.

This will configure firebase.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio Code or Emacs [Link](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor?tab=vscode)

Answer (score 0):

You can still code, but it won't compile, since Flutter SDK needs the Gradle and other tools(that comes with android studio) to be compiled and run in Android, and the flutter doctor in the command line will complain too and won't let you do much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you want to download [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) and get the dart & flutter extensions in it, but you need [AVD](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds) which is provided with Android Studio to run your applications or you can use any other emulator.
Needless to say you also need the [Flutter SDK](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install).

Answer (score 0):

You could try https://dartpad.dev/flutter if you're not planning anything big. It's a flutter version of the dart playground and it lets you test some flutter features, but (as far as I know) it's limited to one file only. And you won't be able to use 3rd party libraries too.